# Obtaining a time difference greater than three days between two columns - MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have three columns, `Created`, `Resolved` and `ID`. I would like to have a query that displays the tickets that were not resolved within 3 days that have been created within the last 30 days

I also require that it shows the `ID` column so I can see which tickets haven't been resolved within the three day time period.

| Created | Resolved | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-02-08 10:39:34 | 2017-05-05 10:18:41 | 1 |
| 2017-02-08 13:49:42 | 2017-02-09 16:08:11 | 2 |
| 2017-02-09 10:15:09 | 2017-02-09 10:18:55 | 3 |

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: MySQL Workbench

Comment: post a minimal example of your table, the desired output and the query you have already tried!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it (preferably with code samples, provided input and the expected output) in order to get a (useful) answer. In its current status, your question will be probably closed soon; it's difficult to produce an answer when the question doesn't provide enough information. Post the table structure (the `CREATE` statement) and the query you have tried.

Comment: Please see the table above. 

The Desired output is to show the difference in Days between Created and Resolved Columns and to display the ID number next to the difference. I only want Tickets that have been created within the last 30 days 


          SELECT * Created, Resolved, ID 
          FROM   tickets
          WHERE  DATEDIFF(resolved, created) >= 3

Is what I have tried, an answer found below

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`datediff`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function to compare two dates:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tickets
WHERE  DATEDIFF(resolved, created) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want something like:

```
where (resolved is null or resolved > date_sub(created, interval 3 day))
```

I'm not sure what the "within the period of 30 days" means.

There is no reason to take the difference of dates in any time unit.  You can simply compare dates to dates.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining this clearly. What I meant to say is I only want to list tickets that were created from (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)

Answer (score 0):

The following was the solution to the problem I was having

```
Select Created, Resolved, id, Queue from Tickets
WHERE Created > (NOW() - interval 30 day) AND Datediff(created, Resolved) > 3;
```